# insert date object to json

Tags: javascript, json, date, amcharts

I have this `json` which i need to work with `amCharts` line chart,

```
        var chartData = [{
            date: "2009/10/2",
            value: 5,
            name: 5
        }, {
            date: "2009/10/3",
            value: 15,
            name: 5

        }, {
            date: "2009/10/4",
            value: 13,
            name: 10
        }, {
            date: "2009/10/5",
            value: 17,
            name: 30
        }, {
            date: "2009/10/6",
            value: 15,
            name: 5
        }, {
            date: "2009/10/7",
            value: 19,
            name: 5
        }];
```

in order to be compatible with `amCharts` i need to assign date value as a Date object so i did through the following function,

```
        function parseDate(){

            for( var i = 0; i < chartData.length; ++i ) {
                var dateArray = chartData[i]["date"].split("/");

                chartData[i]["date"] =  new Date(Number(dateArray[0]), Number(dateArray[1])-1, Number(dateArray[2]));
                window.alert(chartData[i]["date"]);//for debugging purposes
            }
            return chartData;
        }
```

But still i get an empty graph with no lines.. :( but if i hard code the json as follows,

```
        var chartData = [{
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 2),
            value: 5,
            name: 5
        }, {
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 3),
            value: 15,
            name: 5

        }, {
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 4),
            value: 13,
            name: 10
        }, {
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 5),
            value: 17,
            name: 30
        }, {
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 6),
            value: 15,
            name: 5
        }, {
            date: new Date(2009, 10, 7),
            value: 19,
            name: 5
        }];
```

The chart is displayed ,Please help me on this one.

Thank you very much :)

**EDIT: CODE TO GENERATE GRAPH (FYI)**

```
        AmCharts.ready(function () {

            parseDate();

            // SERIAL CHART    
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.pathToImages = "../amcharts/images/";
            chart.zoomOutButton = {
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                backgroundAlpha: 0.15
            };
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.categoryField = "date";

            // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is inited) and call zoomChart method when it happens
            chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

            // AXES
            // category                
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
            categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
            categoryAxis.dashLength = 2;
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
            categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";


            var i = 0;
            for (var key in chartData[0]) {
                if (key != 'date') {
                    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                    valueAxis.offset = i * 40;
                    valueAxis.dashLength = 4;
                    valueAxis.axisColor = "#FF6600";
                    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                    // GRAPH
                    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                    graph.valueAxis = valueAxis; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
                    graph.type = "line";
                    graph.title = "infection # " + i;
                    graph.valueField = key;

                    graph.customBullet = "images/star.gif"; // bullet for all data points
                    graph.bulletSize = 14; // bullet image should be a rectangle (width = height)
                    graph.customBulletField = "customBullet"; // this will make the graph to display custom bullet (red star)
                    chart.addGraph(graph);
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }


            // CURSOR
            var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
            chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
            chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

            // SCROLLBAR
            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

            // LEGEND
            var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            legend.marginLeft = 110;
            chart.addLegend(legend);

            // WRITE
            chart.write("chartdiv");
        });
```

Comment: What happens if you hard code `chartData[i]["date"] = new Date(2009, 10, 7)`?

Comment: same result..i did as `new Date(2010,10,i)` but still an empty graph..now im wondering whthr it is an issue with the cde i generate the graph...but it works fine if i directly pass the json with date objects as shown :( @MrCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function parseDate() {
  for( var i = 0; i < chartData.length; ++i )
    chartData[i]["date"] =  new Date(chartData[i]["date"]);
  return chartData;
}
```

Comment: as much as i wished for this to work, i got the same result..and empty chart :( but thank you for the reply :)

Comment: I don't know if this would make any difference, but could you try `chartData[i].date =  new Date(chartData[i].date);`?

Comment: HEY...thank you..yous worked..even mine worked..i think it was something wrong with the browser..thanks for the help :) :)

Comment: @PulkitGoyal: I followed your code, i used your parseDate() method, but still i am not getting the chart correctly. I am passing the values dynamically.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal: Forget to add a thing in my previous comment, i am using IE8.